# software that convert the production rule to search tree

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is there any software that take production rules and convert them to search tree or decision tree??

Thank you =)

Comment: Emoticons are generally frowned upon as they don't clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a rule engine like JBoss Drools,
it is often used to model tons of rules that result in one or more decisions,
Such as credit approval and credit intrest rate or insurance approval and insurance fee or medical decisions.